# Why these Log Filters takes to much time to display the result in textview in Android?

Tags: android, logcat

I want to display only my TAG Log in textview
I am using these filters but it take to much time to display the log in textview.

**I used these filters**

```
logcat TAG:V *:S  
logcat | find TAG  
logcat | grep TAG  
logcat TAG:* *:s
```

**Below is my code..**

```
public class LogsUtil {

    private static final String TAG = LogsUtil.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final String processId = Integer.toString(android.os.Process.myPid());

    public static StringBuilder readLogs() {

        StringBuilder logBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat TAG:V *:S");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                logBuilder.append(line + "\n");

             //   Log.i("LogUtil Sujeet",logBuilder.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLog failed", e);
        }
        return logBuilder;
    }
}
```

Desplaying the logcat in textview in mainactivity..

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

    StringBuilder result = LogsUtil.readLogs();
    tv.setText(result.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: Use method tracing in your IDE to determine where you are spending your time. Bear in mind that `logcat` is not guaranteed to be on all Android devices.

Comment: You are buffering the entire logcat. Yes, that will take time.

Comment: Any solution ? I want to display quickly in textview. Thanks 4 your answer.